# Checking for and dropping an existing table via C# and SMO

Tags: c#, smo

I am trying to look for a SQL table by name and if it exists drop it. This all needs to be done in C# using SMO.

To complicate it a bit more the table also has a schema other then "dbo".

Ultimatly the table will be recreated via SMO (I have this working) but I have to make sure it is not there before I can recreate it.

All of the examples that I have seen seem to be creating and then dropping the table all in the same context. In my case the table will have been created and populated in a previous session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First question is, why can you not drop and recreate with DDL?

And in answer to your question:

```
Table table = new Table(myDatabase, "MyTable", "MySchema");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have actually gone down the same route but different path: 

myTable.Schema = "MySchema"

The table structure itself is determined on the fly by parsing an XML schema.

Answer (score 12):

```
var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
var server = new Server(new ServerConnection(connection));

db = server.Databases["YourFavDB"];

db.Tables["YourHatedTable"].Drop();
```

Comment: The only one to answer the question and not a single upvote until now. Is there any justice on SO?

Comment: There's no mention of schema here. It could be either completely reasonable, or dangerous to assume the schema is dbo, depending on your environment

Comment: Good answer, I think DropIfExists() would be better

Answer (score 4):

I think the best approach would be:

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database myDataBase = myServer.Databases["myDataBaseName"];
bool tableExists= myDataBase.Tables.Contains("myTable");
if (tableExists)
{
   myDataBase.Tables["myTable"].Drop();
}
```

Comment: This should absolutely be the accepted answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just wrap your DROP TABLE statement in a try/catch block, and discard any errors that occur?

Anyway, the sql to determine if a table exists is:

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[TableName]') AND type in (N'U'))
```

Comment: It goes against my grain to use errors for program flow control. 

Thanks for the response.

Comment: Well, couldn't you use the IF EXISTS I provided to check first, if you don't like the Try/Catch?